# printf() and scanf() in order?

Tags: c, linux, string

I am beginner in C programming. I don't understand one thing. Why if I put down that

```
printf("write down any whole number:");
scanf("%d",&(any int variable));
```

When I use **gdb(debugger)** it shows me that CPU executes `printf()`, but doesn't write anything, then goes to the `scanf()` instruction and after that writes String and takes it to analyze by `scanf` function.

I am using GCC and Linux Debian

Question: Why `printf` is executed only after `scanf`?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sur why, something probably done by the optimisation, but to resolve this you can use an `fflush()` to print it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you saw in the debugger — and great that you used one as a beginner! — the printf has been executed alright. The characters are now in a buffer which will be flushed when a newline is output or the buffer is full which may happen at 4096 bytes, or some other amount, often a power of 2. The reason for the buffering is efficiency: The actual transfer to the terminal is slow. If it happened for every single character it would be unnecessarily slow. The fix is to print a newline, or flush explicitly with flush.

Comment: Thank you very much. It blew up my mind when I write   printf("hello");   then I added a loop and it turned out that printf was executed after loop. )))))

Comment: I mean "printf was executed after loop" not executed, but flushed

Comment: Reading the linked answer I realize that my answer is only half the truth: Even without the newline your text should appear before the program waits for input at scanf; this is specified exactly for this use case. So, what I wrote is not wrong but the interesting question is just *why* the buffer is not flushed before the scanf, as it should be. It could be that you use an IDE which displays the output e.g. in a text window or such. For some reason the standard output connected to the program running in the IDE does not identify itself as a terminal (i.e., `isatty(fd)` returns 0).

Comment: Thank you. I read linked answer too. And I got it))). But you gave me the main idea)))